Fetching Values from XML in snowflake query which is stored in column
Hi I have one table where XML value is store in the column
<ArrayOfValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ValueIncluded>
    <Value1>bf3079af-47be-49ec-ab64-ba1b6e360df9</Value1>
    <Value2>false</Value2>
    <Value3>true</Value3>
    <Value4>1</Value4>
    <Value5>false</Value5>
    <Value6>false</Value6>
    <Value7>GlobalDocument</Value7>
    <Value8>true</Value8>
    <Value9>0</Value9>
  </ValueIncluded>
  <ValueIncluded>
    <Value1>e5d9aa84-dccf-455c-8205-8d6027dcf654</Value1>
    <Value2>false</Value2>
    <Value3>true</Value3>
    <Value4>2</Value4>
    <Value5>false</Value5>
    <Value6>false</Value6>
    <Value7>GlobalDocument</Value7>
    <Value8>true</Value8>
    <Value9>0</Value9>
    <Value10>false</Value10>
    <Value11>true</Value11>
  </ValueIncluded>
</ArrayOfValues>

I need to read the value1,2,3 and so on, I tried their documentation and many attempts but getting the Id of table but failed to read the values from XML.
SELECT  ID, PARSE_XML(MyColumn):"ArrayOfValues":"ValueIncluded"[1]:"Value1"::TEXT AS Val1, PARSE_XML(MyColumn):"ArrayOfValues":"ValueIncluded"[1]:"Value2"::TEXT AS Val2, PARSE_XML(MyColumn):"ArrayOfValues":"ValueIncluded"[1]:"Value3"::TEXT AS Val3, PARSE_XML(MyColumn):"ArrayOfValues":"ValueIncluded"[1]:"Value4"::TEXT AS Val4, PARSE_XML(MyColumn):"ArrayOfValues":"ValueIncluded"[1]:"Value5"::TEXT AS Val5 FROM MyTable where id='MyValue123'
I tried more method but did not get any promising result, anyone has any insights can help here.

unless the XML handling has changes A LOT since I wrote example code last, you cannot use the nice accessors, you have to use the super ugly getter functions

So, assuming there is "always two ValueIncluded" objects, you can use fixed access like:
with fake_data(txt) as (
    select * from values ('<ArrayOfValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ValueIncluded>
    <Value1>bf3079af-47be-49ec-ab64-ba1b6e360df9</Value1>
    <Value2>false</Value2>
    <Value3>true</Value3>
    <Value4>1</Value4>
    <Value5>false</Value5>
    <Value6>false</Value6>
    <Value7>GlobalDocument</Value7>
    <Value8>true</Value8>
    <Value9>0</Value9>
  </ValueIncluded>
  <ValueIncluded>
    <Value1>e5d9aa84-dccf-455c-8205-8d6027dcf654</Value1>
    <Value2>false</Value2>
    <Value3>true</Value3>
    <Value4>2</Value4>
    <Value5>false</Value5>
    <Value6>false</Value6>
    <Value7>GlobalDocument</Value7>
    <Value8>true</Value8>
    <Value9>0</Value9>
    <Value10>false</Value10>
    <Value11>true</Value11>
  </ValueIncluded>
</ArrayOfValues>')
)

SELECT 
    parse_xml(txt) as xml,
    XMLGET(xml, 'ValueIncluded',0) as ValueIncluded0,
    XMLGET(xml, 'ValueIncluded',1) as ValueIncluded1,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded0, 'Value1'),'$')::text as val0_1,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded0, 'Value2'),'$')::text as val0_2,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded0, 'Value3'),'$')::text as val0_3,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded1, 'Value1'),'$')::text as val1_1,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded1, 'Value2'),'$')::text as val1_2,
    GET(XMLGET(ValueIncluded1, 'Value3'),'$')::text as val1_3,
FROM fake_data


For variable array size:
SELECT 
    v.seq,
    v.index,
    GET(XMLGET(v.Value, 'Value1'),'$')::text as val0_1,
    GET(XMLGET(v.Value, 'Value2'),'$')::text as val0_2,
    GET(XMLGET(v.Value, 'Value3'),'$')::text as val0_3,

FROM fake_data,
table(flatten(input=>get(parse_xml(txt), '$'))) as v

gives:

